# Should the ti99 tag be changed to ti-99?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

For consistency, I think the `ti99` tag should be changed to `ti-99` and `ti99` should be a synonym for it.

What do you think?

When you look at other tags, you see a trend of "computer-model".  Such as `apple-ii` and `atari-st`, `commodore-pet`, etc.

The hierarchy I would suggest (tag plus synonyms) would be:

```
ti-99
    ti99
```

The only reason I wouldn't suggest making `texas-instruments` the main tag is that it's a little long and most people probably refer to it as TI anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, the convention we've adopted is to have hyphens.  I've created the [ti-99](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-99) synonym.

I have not created a [texas-instruments](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) or [ti](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti).  We can do that as and when necessary.

The recommendation here is that use of a tag containing only a manufacturer name should only be applied if discussing more than one product of that manufacturer.  Tagging with, for example, [ti](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti) and [ti-99](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-99) or [apple](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [apple-ii](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii) is unnecessary.

Comment: Or you could, of course, use the tags relevant to the product(s) in question. For example, a question discussing the Apple I and Apple II could be tagged as [apple-i] [apple-ii], but doesn't really benefit significantly from *also* being tagged [apple] (unless you are aiming for answers from people who are experts in Apple).

Comment: Note: Something is really weird with the `ti99`/`ti-99` tag. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1416/357 is tagged `ti99` according to the UI, but clicking on the tag brings me to the list of questions for `ti-99`. The other tags on the question have tag hover popups, but not `ti99`. If I follow the right-hand "about" link, I arrive at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/ti-99/info which is a 404.