# Should [datageneral] have a hyphen?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Similar to [Should the ti99 tag be changed to ti-99?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/278), should [datageneral](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datageneral) be replaced with [data-general](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-general) for consistency, or is there a stylisation (like *apple ][*) that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Sounds a bit superfluous to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the company was always known as Data General and, as far as I know, never used any execrable affectations like camel case or mis-capitalisation, then yes, it should be hyphenated.

That would keep it consistent with our other tags.

Answer (score 2):

```
updating post history, 2 rows affected
updating posts, 2 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [data-general] and [datageneral] complete!
```

Tag successfully renamed.

In general, tags should be hyphenated.